# Ember Bindings: binding a property to its a child's property

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a Ember.View.ParentView that has two childViews. One of which is a ContainerView. The other child of ParentView needs to access the childViews of the ContainerView.

In ContainerView, I have tried using:

```
 this.get('parentView').set('foo', this.get('childViews') )
```

hoping this will set the property in ParentView to an array of childView views. However, in the second childView of ParentView, calling:

```
 foo = this.get('parentView').get('foo')
```

returns an Array of Classes instead of Instances. So I am trying to use bindings now. How can I create a binding of a property to a classes child's property?

Comment: Is it possible to create jsfiddle describing your problem? http://jsfiddle.net/6p6XJ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `viewName` property for setting up names of childViews instances in the parent instance (see relevant commit [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/212)):

```
App.MyParentView = Ember.View.extend({

  containerViewChilds: 'fooContainer.childViews',

  aContainerView: Ember.ContainerView.extend({
    // ...
  }),

  anotherView: Ember.View.extend({
    containerViewChildsBinding: 'parentView.containerViewChilds'
    // ...
  })
});
```

`App.MyParentView` template:

```
{{view view.aContainerView viewName="fooContainer"}}

{{view view.anotherView}}
```